# Easy way to have Homebrew list all package dependencies

Tags: homebrew, dependency-management

Is there anyway to have the command `brew` show all the installed or optional dependencies for any given package? It would also be helpful to see which of the install packages are themselves the dependencies of others packages.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use info command like.

```
brew info ffmpeg
```

It will show you information and dependencies of formula. Also, it shows if this package installed by a tick after name of it.

Comment: Is there no way to also see which packages depend on the installation you are getting info for?

Comment: @OliverDechant You want `brew uses --installed {formula}`.

Comment: `brew info` doesn't show you dependencies of dependencies, whereas `brew deps --tree` does.

Answer (score 348):

For all packages:

```
brew deps --tree --installed
```

For one package only (e.g.):

```
brew deps --tree --installed vim
```

*Thanks to [rob-kovacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535738/rob-kovacs) for suggesting the `--tree` addition*

See this helpful article for details: https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/untangling-your-homebrew-dependencies/
Especially if you're interested in creating a graph of the dependency tree.

Comment: To check only one package, e.g. `brew deps --tree --installed vim`.

Comment: Is there a faster way? Takes 1s. I'd like to check deps are installed everytime before running one of my clis.

Comment: @NeoZoom.lua `brew deps --tree <foo>` is enough. Just tested `brew deps --tree zstd`.

Answer (score 92):

Here is a command that will list all formulas that aren't dependents of any other formulas (leaves), and for each of them lists all of its dependencies.

Sample output line:

```
awscli: gdbm readline sqlite tcl-tk xz
```

Command:

```
brew leaves | xargs brew deps --formula --for-each | sed "s/^.*:/$(tput setaf 4)&$(tput sgr0)/"
```

Alternate command without xargs:

```
brew deps --formula --for-each $(brew leaves) | sed "s/^.*:/$(tput setaf 4)&$(tput sgr0)/"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm clearing space on my Mac and this is helpful.

Answer (score 28):

Command:

```
brew deps --include-build --tree $(brew leaves)
```

Convenient alias:

```
alias brewdeps="brew leaves | xargs brew deps --include-build --tree"
```

This way you will get **dependencies printed hierarchically** and each package will be printed only once.

Answer (score 23):

I found the `brew deps --tree` switch is also very helpful to visualize dependencies just in the command line. From the official doc:

```
brew deps --tree [--1] [filters] [--annotate] (formulae|--installed):
Show dependencies as a tree. When given multiple formula arguments, output
individual trees for every formula.
```

Example1:

```
brew deps --tree fontconfig
```

Output1:

```
fontconfig
└── freetype
    └── libpng
```

Example2:

```
brew deps --tree --1 fontconfig
```

Output2:

```
fontconfig
└── freetype
```

and there are more switches explained by:

```
brew help deps
```